# How to use generics with Angular CDK's Dialog.open<?????>

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics, angular-cdk

I'm trying to figure out what interfaces to put inside the generics section of the `open` function from [Angular's CDK Dialog](https://material.angular.io/cdk/dialog/overview). Note that this is not angular material!!

This is what I have figured out so far

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open<IResult, unknown, IInputData>(FooComponent, {
  width: '350px',
  data: { x: 10 } as IInputData
})

dialogRef.closed.subscribe((data: IResult) => { ... }
```

As you can see I already figured out 2 generics (the first and the last). But it is still unclear what the middle generic should be. So, because generics aren't mentioned in the documentation I checked out the interface of `open` which is

```
open<R = unknown, D = unknown, C = unknown>(component: ComponentType<C>, config?: DialogConfig<D, DialogRef<R, C>>): DialogRef<R, C>;
open<R = unknown, D = unknown, C = unknown>(template: TemplateRef<C>, config?: DialogConfig<D, DialogRef<R, C>>): DialogRef<R, C>;
open<R = unknown, D = unknown, C = unknown>(componentOrTemplateRef: ComponentType<C> | TemplateRef<C>, config?: DialogConfig<D, DialogRef<R, C>>): DialogRef<R, C>;
```

It is generic `D` that I'm interested in. Its used in `DialogConfig` which looks like this

```
/** Configuration for opening a modal dialog. */
export declare class DialogConfig<D = unknown, R = unknown, C extends BasePortalOutlet = BasePortalOutlet> {
    ...

    /**
     * Providers that will be exposed to the contents of the dialog. Can also
     * be provided as a function in order to generate the providers lazily.
     */
    providers?: StaticProvider[] | ((dialogRef: R, config: DialogConfig<D, R, C>, container: C) => StaticProvider[]);
    /**
     * Component into which the dialog content will be rendered. Defaults to `CdkDialogContainer`.
     * A configuration object can be passed in to customize the providers that will be exposed
     * to the dialog container.
     */
    container?: Type<C> | {
        type: Type<C>;
        providers: (config: DialogConfig<D, R, C>) => StaticProvider[];
    };
 ...
```

Here is where I'm lost. Any suggestions what D might be?

Comment: D is the type to be used for the data to be added to the dialog: `data?: D | null = null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D` is the type of the data being injected into the child component. As per the [source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/04deba8c966cb127168218f3f91d986e04a8b6c1/src/cdk/dialog/dialog-config.ts#L81):

```
/** Data being injected into the child component. */
data?: D | null = null;
```

Comment: Thats what you might think. But I don't think the `D` I'm talking about is the same `D` as mentioned in the documentation. This can be seen from the `open` interfaces I have listed, in which `data` is `R`!

Comment: Isn't `R` the result data and `D` the input data ? Looks like `R` refers to the result data on the `Dialog.open()` side, and to a `DialogRef` on the `DialogConfig` side.

Comment: `D` seems to consistently refer to the input data that is passed to the dialog though.

Comment: Yes true, my mistake. So the generics are: `dialog.open<IOutput, IInput, FooComponent>(....)` This seems to work :)